# Javascript to hide value if it's zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form who gives data from database
I have number type inputs.
I want to hide and leave empty the input that displays "0", without replace it in database after submit.

I found how to do it with table cells.
But not with inputs.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(cells[i].textContent, 10) === 0) {
 cells[i].innerHTML = ' ';

  }
}
</script>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Filter input selection by value where it equals 0 with `filter()` function and then remove these elements from DOM not be submitted with the form with `remove()` function

```
   $('input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() === 0; }).remove();
```